# Powershell Best way to parse string content

Tags: powershell

Im atempting to parse a webrequest.  What is best way?  Get the variable to a String array or Object array?
The webrequest supplies a string object, but I can't split by line because some lines are multiple..
Would comma delimit be best bet?  Im having difficulty and running out of ideas.

```
    $webresponse = (invoke-webrequest -Uri "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR99VhhEfs2VKo3FWuTqC66vEzlmiqAODGiAaicmswvyf3PdtOX2YYoP72ou52CdUpgqEbr9OAK6X0x/pub?output=csv").content
```

If I split by comma

```
$webresponse.Split(",")
```

I can get it into a string array, but then not sure on next step OR even if this is most efficient way through this task.
Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The response is CSV, as the URL indicates with the `output=csv` parameter.

Use the `ConvertFrom-Csv` cmdlet.

```
$webresponse = Invoke-Webrequest -Uri "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR99VhhEfs2VKo3FWuTqC66vEzlmiqAODGiAaicmswvyf3PdtOX2YYoP72ou52CdUpgqEbr9OAK6X0x/pub?output=csv"
$data = $webresponse.Content | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ","
```

`$data` will be an array.

```py
$data.Count
# 175
```

PowerShell will assume the CSV has headers by default, which conveniently is the case here.

```py
$data[0]
# Tweet                                       DateTime                   
# -----                                       --------                 
# SPOT PLATINUM FALLS OVER 5% TO $1,007.20/OZ January 11, 2021 at 08:25AM

$data[0].Tweet
# SPOT PLATINUM FALLS OVER 5% TO $1,007.20/OZ
```